# Writing a standard set of algorithms in C++

Tags: c++, stl

There are a number of algorithms which I have created over time which I find myself reusing in each successive project. To date, I have simply cut a pasted the code into the relevant project. However, it would be more efficient to create a library (or libraries) of algorithms which I could then just include as required, in much the same way that I include the Standard Libraries.

What is the best way/practice for creating such a library? Should I create a class which contains a set of static functions? Or am I looking at this the wrong way?

Any advice that you could offer would most appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Make an .h/hpp file and include it whenever you need it?

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. Yes, my question doesn't really relate to the algorithms themselves, but rather the way in which I could make their reuse as easy as including a .h file, in much the same manner as I regularly include the math.h header to use the mathematical functions therein. Have I unwittingly been asking about C++ templates?

Comment: @POD you can make a .h file yourself.

Comment: Create .h/.hpp files for inclusion. Compile .cc/.cpp files into static/shared libs. Put the includes in your `INCLUDE_PATH` and the libs in your `LIB_PATH`. Copy pasting is evil. You must stop it now! If you take the shared library approach, then all your algorithm bugfixes get reflected across all projects automatically.

Comment: Creating a class with static methods is almost certainly the wrong way. There is no need for this in C++. In general, you should create a library. Whether it is compiled or headers only depends on the details of your algorithms.

Comment: Yes, thank you. I suspected that the use of static methods was not the correct approach from the point of view of oop. I already use .h files as a matter of course, but to date they have always been used to define a class. As such, I have needed to create an instance of the class to use the functionality.

Answer (score 3):

Just do this the same way as the standard library: Create a set of free-functions in your own namespace. Typically the free-functions would take a number of iterators that tell the algorithm which items to operate upon.

EDIT: There's no reason to use static class members in C++, that's a Java idiom because it doesn't have namespace level free-functions.

Comment: Thank you. Indeed, I was careful not to use the term 'static class', but various comments on the web referred to the use of static members. At any rate, it didn't seem like a good approach from a point of oop.